# Kile will not work on Ubuntu (utf8x.def)

Tags: ubuntu, kile

I just installed Kile on Ubuntu and I can't get it to work.

Even just starting with one of the templates I continue to get the error:

> ```
> [PDFLaTeX]finished with exit code 1
> /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/input.sty:131:File 'utf8x.def not found.\endinput
> ```

I have spent quite a while trying to figure this out...

Answer (score 17):

You can install the Package `texlive-latex-extra`. That should resolve the problem.

This seems to be a bug in Ubuntu which does not pull in this packet when installing Kile.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 7):

`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` will not work any longer on Ubuntu/Kile. I had the same problem as I updated from 10.04 to 11.11.

Now you simply have to use:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Just remove the `x` from `utf8x`.

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` really works. I was getting the error finished with exit code 1 and was not compiling. Now it is giving finished with exit code 2 but the document is compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without seeing your doc, it is hard to to know what is wrong. Does this test work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\end{document}
```

if it works, something else is wrong and we'd like to see your doc or a minimal example showing your problem.

I do not thing `utf8x` and `ucs` is recommended any more.

BTW: Which TeX Live installation are you using, the Ubuntu one or the one from TUG?