# utf8x.def not found Mac

Tags: unicode, mac, mactex

I'm trying to compile a latex file from `coq` on Mac and get the following error:

`File utf8x.def not found.`

Where can I find `utf8x.def`?

Most of the other answers pertain to ubuntu and don't work on mac.

Comment: No TeX Live installation on Mac OS that I know of puts files in `/usr/share`, so your question is ill-posed.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed BasicTeX or a manual install on Linux, you can use `tlmgr` and run `sudo tlmgr install ucs` which installs the ucs package which includes utf8x.

If you installed with `apt-get` on linux, use `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`

Comment: You already gave this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387532/124577

Comment: If one installs MacTeX, there is no need to add `ucs`, because it's already included.

Comment: @egreg True, I've updated to say BasicTeX (the smaller version of MacTeX) which is what I installed.

Comment: @TeXnician My other similar answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43779/kile-will-not-work-on-ubuntu-utf8x-def/387535#387535 was deleted as an improper answer because the question was ubuntu related.  They recommended I post I new Mac specific question.  I was worried they would also delete my answer on the post you cited since it gave a mac answer to an ubuntu question.  Thus, I created a new mac specific question as an attempt at doing the right thing, though it still seems to be wrong to people and a duplicated of the ubuntu question...

Comment: can you specify how to resolve this issue on macOS?

Comment: `sudo tlmgr install ucs` should work on Mac provided you've install BasicTeX or MacTeX already.